# How to filter 'cat' output to only display a portion of text?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to find a way to filter the output of a `cat` command to only display the text included between two points. I need to put this on a script.

More to the point, given the following sample text

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus        
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet
nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 

-------------
Release Notes
-------------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus        
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet
nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 

------------
Known Issues
------------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus        
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet
nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
```

I need the output to **only** display the text between the

```
-------------
Release Notes
-------------
```

and

```
------------
Known Issues
------------
```

blocks.

I've tried something with `grep` but being text on multiple lines, it doesn't work (or at least I was not able to make it work).

Comment: Some words on the text that I put within "code" tags were highlighted in blue (at least on my screen); it was not intentional, it must be something done by the site; I didn't mean to give emphasis to these bits of text.

Comment: The question mentions `cat` but it is worth noting that in general case it could be something else that generates output. If a tool can accept `cat` output as its own input then it can accept almost anything. To read a file there is `tool < file` syntax (additionally some tools accept filename(s) as parameter(s), like `awk` in K.Mitko's answer). There is hardly ever (never?) a job for `cat` unless you want to con**cat**enate two or more inputs.

Comment: I've used `cat` because it is one of the simplest ways to display the content of a file, it does not necessarily need to concatenate something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try awk:

`awk '/Release Notes/,/Known Issues/' file | head -n -3 | tail -n +4`

The first command extracts the text between "Release notes" and "Known issue", the head and tail are there to remove first and last lines from your example. If you don't want awk to print the matched lines, you should use:

`awk '/^Release Notes$/{flag=1;next}/^Known Issues$/{flag=0}flag' file`

Comment: That's the right answer, with not a `cat` in sight. :-)